# Powershell - further process of import-csv data

Tags: csv, powershell

I've managed to import-csv data from .csv file using:

```
import-csv -Delimiter "`t"-Header @("planid","partnb","id","type","idsymbol","actual") data.txt | Where-Object {$_.ID -eq "057 L13" -or $_.ID -eq "047 L70.6"}
```

with the result of:

```
planid   : TL_QL FRT Knuckle RH 2WD CNC
partnb   : M10   4.1   242
id       : 047 L70.6
type     : Hodn-X
idsymbol : xValue
actual   : 70.7187445

planid   : TL_QL FRT Knuckle RH 2WD CNC
partnb   : M10   4.1   242
id       : 057 L13
type     : Hodn-Z
idsymbol : zValue
actual   : 13.0685455
```

now I need to do some actions (to run a script) based on **actual** value. (e.g. if smaler or bigger than, do this ...) what will be the best approach to do it?

Comment: Depends on what actions you want to take.  In any case, you should start by assigning the result to a variable (`$rows = import-csv ...`), and then use a `foreach-object` loop to manipulate the data.  eg: `$rows | foreach { "id: " + $_.id + "; actual: " + $_.actual }`  You can skip the variable if you know you only need to go over the data once (`import-csv ... | foreach { ... }`), but it can result in some pretty long lines of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should store your imported data in a variable:

```
$dataset = import-csv -Delimiter "`t"-Header @("planid","partnb","id","type","idsymbol","actual") data.txt | Where-Object {$_.ID -eq "057 L13" -or $_.ID -eq "047 L70.6"}
```

Thereafter, you have a few options depending on what you know about data.

If you know what rownumbers to match for, you could access it and check for properties directly and execute code, example:

```
# Code to check if property id of row 3 equals a specific id or planid contains TL_QL
if($dataset[2].id -eq "057 L13" -or $dataset[2].planid -match "TL_QL"){ 
    # Your code to do something 
}
```

If you don't know the row and want to iterate every object, you do the following:

```
# Improved for readability; you could use $_ directly
$dataset|Foreach-object { 
      $row = $_;
      if($row.id -eq "057"  -or $row.planid -match "TL_QL"){
        # do something
      }
}
```

You can mix and match with -and -or operators, together with logical operators such as -eq, -lt, -gt, -match, -nomatch etc.

I'm assuming from your question, you want to match the "actual" property to some int/double value. You might then want to use for example -lt or -gt. Example: $row.actual -lt 70 (if value is less than 70).

For more information about logical operators see about_logical_operators or this link: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847789.aspx

Comment: `$dataset[2]` would refer to the *3rd* row, not the *2nd*

Comment: Good catch, too early in the morning before coffee! Updated now